# RxJS ajax returns null response

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5, rxjs-dom

I'm trying to retrieve some data using rxjs. It returns 200, but response is null. Is there any extra step to retrieve response?

Test api; https://reqres.in

Thanks.

```
import {ajax} from 'rxjs/observable/dom/ajax';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


ajax.get({
            url: "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2",
            // crossDomain: true,
            method: "GET",
        })
            .subscribe(data => {
                console.log(data)
                debugger
            })
```

[image]

Comment: take data.json() instead of data only

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Never mind,

It should be `ajax()` not `ajax.get()`